# Cómo ajustar esta consulta SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

Buen día, quisiera ayuda de como proceder para que a partir de estos datos de la tabla academica:

| persona | consecutivoReg | estuido | codiegoEstudio | fechaTerminacion |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | 1 | Tecnico | 01 | 22/05/1998 |
| 1111 | 2 | Universitario | 3 | 13/04/2004 |
| 1111 | 3 | Especializacion | 04 | 08/09/2007 |
| 2222 | 1 | Tecnico | 01 | 25/07/1970 |
| 2222 | 2 | Universitario | 03 | 05/11/1975 |
| 3333 | 1 | Tecnologo | 02 | 28/09/2010 |

pueda obtener el ultimo nivel de estudio(técnico,tecnologo o universitario) de cada persona

| persona | consecutivoReg | estuido | fechaTerminacion |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | 2 | Universitario | 08/09/2007 |
| 2222 | 2 | Universitario | 05/11/1975 |
| 3333 | 1 | Tecnologo | 28/09/2010 |

se me ha ocurrido que primero se debe hacer como un filtro de codiegoEstudio('01','02','03','3') con lo que se descartarían los otros estudios y sobre esos resultados elergir de cada persona los que tengan el mayor consecutivoReg o la mayor fechaTerminacion

```
SELECT ac.persona,MAX(ac.consecutivoReg),ac.estuido,ac.fechaTerminacion
FROM academica ac
WHERE (ac.codiegoEstudio = '01' OR ac.codiegoEstudio = '02' OR ac.codiegoEstudio = '03' ac.codiegoEstudio = '3')
GROUP BY ac.persona,ac.estuido,ac.fechaTerminacion
```

pero me sale esto:

| persona | consecutivoReg | estuido | fechaTerminacion |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | 1 | Tecnico | 22/05/1998 |
| 1111 | 2 | Universitario | 08/09/2007 |
| 2222 | 1 | Tecnico | 25/07/1970 |
| 2222 | 2 | Universitario | 05/11/1975 |
| 3333 | 1 | Tecnologo | 28/09/2010 |

Al parecer si hace el filtro por  codiegoEstudio('01','02','03','3')  pero no funciona el MAX(ac.consecutivoReg)

Gracias a la persona que me pueda orientar sobre el proceso que debo hacer para que consulta tenga el resultado esperado.

PD:  ¿Por qué hay codiegoEstudio '03'(Universitario) y codiegoEstudio '3'(Universitario)? R.// la info ya estaba ingresada así, puede haber sido un error del que programo la base de datos pero ya hay mucha información así.

Comment: `consecutivoReg` es tipo numérico?

Comment: @L.Ronquillo acabo de hacer una consulta con DUMP para mirar el tipo de dato de consecutivoReg  y es Typ=2 NUMBER......

Answer (score 0):

Debes definir con precisión qué campo tiene precedencia para determinar cuál es el último nivel de estudio, ya que no pueden ser los dos campos al mismo tiempo. En el ejemplo a continuación estoy asumiendo que la fecha de terminación tiene precedencia y, solo si hay dos registros con la misma fecha de terminación, entonces entra a jugar el consecutivo de registro.

Dado que queremos toda la información, lo que haré es, primero, numerar los registros de cada persona, ordenando por fecha y número de registro, ambos de manera descendente. Finalmente, me quedaré solamente con los registros que tengan el número 1.

Para lograrlo, me valgo de un CTE, donde hago la numeración:

```
with
CTE as (
SELECT   ac.persona
       , ac.consecutivoReg
       , ac.estuido
       , ac.fechaTerminacion
       , row_number() over (partition by ac.persona order by ac.fechaTerminacion desc, ac.consetutivoReg desc) Orden
  FROM academica ac
 WHERE ac.codiegoEstudio in ('01', '02', '03', '3')
)
select pesona, consecutivoReg, estudio, fechaTerminacion
  from CTE
 where Orden = 1;
/
```

Como puedes observar, me valgo de la función de ventana `row_number()` para ordenar los registros. La cláusula `partition by ac.persona` me permite dividir el conjunto en sub-conjuntos para cada persona y re-iniciar el contador a 1 cada vez que se entra a una nueva partición.

Si la precedencia es diferente, puedes ajustar la cláusula `order by` de esta función.

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, le he quitado el  MAX(fechaTerminacion) porque me refería a que debería funcionar el MAX(ac.consecutivoReg) o el MAX(fechaTerminacion) pero no depende de ambos

Comment: No entiendo bien a qué te refieres, en la respuesta no uso la función `max()` en ninguna parte. ¿La leíste? ¿probaste la consulta?

Answer (score 0):

Estuve leyendo tu inquietud en la consulta, puedes usar la siguiente manera para obtener el último nivel de estudio de acuerdo a una persona:

```
SELECT ac.Persona, MAX(ac.ConsecutivoReg) Consecutivo 
   ,(SELECT sc.Estuido 
     FROM estudio sc WHERE sc.Persona = ac.Persona AND sc.ConsecutivoReg = MAX(ac.ConsecutivoReg)) Estuido
   ,(SELECT sc.FechaTerminancion 
     FROM estudio sc WHERE sc.Persona = ac.Persona AND sc.ConsecutivoReg = MAX(ac.ConsecutivoReg)) FechaTerminancion
FROM estudio ac GROUP BY ac.Persona ORDER BY  ac.Persona ASC, MAX(ac.ConsecutivoReg) DESC
```

Este ejemplo fue realizado en SQL Server, puede cambiar algunos nombres de columna, me valí con subconsulta aunque puede afectar un poco el rendimiento.

Saludos

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, le he quitado el  MAX(fechaTerminacion) porque me refería a que debería funcionar el MAX(ac.consecutivoReg) o el MAX(fechaTerminacion) pero no depende de ambos